# Regexp constraint not properly parsed by JAXB

Tags: java, regex, xml, xsd, jaxb

There are similar questions to the one I am about to ask out there but none of them has actually given me what I am looking for. The case is as follows:

This is a referenced part of an XSD file that puts on a constraint on the field 'someNumber'. It is unmarshalled into a POJO and used as a parameter in some webservice method.

```
<xs:simpleType name="someNumber">
      <xs:restriction base="string">
        <xs:pattern value="\d{9,11}"/>  
      </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Below is the parsed Java field

```
@XmlElement(name = "SomeNumber")
 protected String someNumber;
```

On calling this API I am allowed to pass in any String for the number field and still go through.

Ideally, I would love the regexp to be parsed like so

```
 @XmlElement(name = "SomeNumber")
 @Pattern(regexp = "\d{9,11}")
  protected String someNumber;
```

And throw an error if the constraint is violated upon API call.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: \ must be doubled because is an escape character in java string litteral

Comment: It seems like you are wanting the restrictions to be applied/validated in the setter? I think the JAXB approach is to (optionally) do validation only during marshal/unmarshal. Having said that, JAXB is a pluggable architecture and you can pretty easily write your own plugin to change how the code is generated. There are a bunch of open source plugins that you can use as examples.